# Change theme in React via context

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a context where I define my light and dark theme. Then I send the context to app where I defined a state that is passed to my Settings screen via my context provider value.

Here is my questions: If I want to toggle between dark and light via settings, where would I need to put my state? Or can I just define a function in App that I pass down via navigation somehow?

*And my buttons that should toggle the theme are simple onPress buttons in the screen Settings.js, also my theme colors are already imported there via context obviously!*

Please help!

**App.js**

```
import ThemeContext, {themes} from './contexts/ThemeContext';

const App = () => {
const [selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme] = useState(themes.light)


  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={selectedTheme}>
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  
  );
};
```

**ThemeContext.js**

```
import React from "react";
export const themes =  {
     
    dark: {
     
        background:{backgroundColor:"black"},
        text:{backgroundColor:"white"},
  

    },

    light:{
     
        background:{backgroundColor:"white"},
        text:{backgroundColor:"black"},
  

    },
}


const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.dark)
export default ThemeContext
```

Comment: Can you show code about <Stack.Screen>? What is {setting} in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "setSelectedTheme" to your Context-Provider.

```
<ThemeContext.Provider value={{selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme}}>
```

You can than import your ThemeContext in the Compontens you need it and use it this way:

```
const currentTheme = useContext(ThemeContext)
```

If you want to change the Theme, you can then use:

```
currentTheme.setSelectedTheme = "light"
```

wherever you need it.

Comment: Just to add a clarification it seems to be working when I created a function in App that sets the theme then imported it like this in settings: const {selectedTheme, setThemeFunction} = useContext(ThemeContext)

Answer (score 0):

This repository has a good example of how to setup custom theming. https://github.com/florophore/floro-react-native-demo.

In your app.tsx you need something to manage the theme preference. Here is an example of such a provider.

ThemeSet in this example but would likely be a hashmap with keys light 'light' and 'dark'. The values would correspond to your predefined themes.

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

export const ThemePreferenceProvider = (props: Props): React.ReactElement => {
  const [themePreference, setThemePreference] = useState<
    'system' | keyof ThemeSet
  >('system');

  useEffect(() => {
    let closureIsFresh = true;
    AsyncStorage.getItem('theme-preference').then(
      (storedPreference: string | null) => {
        if (closureIsFresh) {
          setThemePreference(
            (storedPreference as keyof ThemeSet | 'system') ?? 'system',
          );
        }
      },
    );
    return () => {
      closureIsFresh = false;
    };
  }, []);

  const selectColorTheme = useCallback(
    (themePreference: 'system' | keyof ThemeSet) => {
      setThemePreference(themePreference);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('theme-preference', themePreference);
    },
    [],
  );

  const rnSystemColorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const currentTheme = useMemo(() => {
    if (themePreference == 'system') {
        if (!rnSystemColorScheme) {
            return (
              (
                Object.keys(initThemes.themeDefinitions) as Array<
                  keyof ThemeSet
                >
              )?.[0] ??
              (initThemes.themeDefinitions[
                defaultTheme
              ] as unknown as keyof ThemeSet)
            );
        }
        return initThemes.themeDefinitions[rnSystemColorScheme as keyof ThemeSet]?.name as keyof ThemeSet;
    }
    return themePreference as keyof ThemeSet;

  }, [themePreference, rnSystemColorScheme])

  return (
    <ThemePreferenceContext.Provider
      value={{
        themePreference,
        selectColorTheme,
        currentTheme
      }}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemePreferenceContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useThemePreference = () => {
  return useContext(ThemePreferenceContext);
};
```

You then can define some pretty useful hooks. So you can use your themes in stylesheets and jsx.

```
interface InjectedStyles {
  palette: Palette;
  paletteColor: <K extends keyof Palette, S extends keyof Palette[K]>(
    key: K,
    shade: S,
    defaultValue?: string,
  ) => ColorValue;
  colorTheme: ColorTheme;
  themeColor: <K extends keyof ThemeColors>(
    key: K,
    variantKey?: keyof ThemeColors[K]['variants'] | 'default',
    defaultValue?: string,
  ) => ColorValue;
  background: ColorValue;
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export const createUseStyles = <
  T extends StyleSheet.NamedStyles<T> | StyleSheet.NamedStyles<any>,
>(
  stylesCallback: (injected: InjectedStyles) => T,
): () => StyleSheet.NamedStyles<T> | StyleSheet.NamedStyles<any> => {
  return () => {
    return useStyles(stylesCallback);
  }
};

const useStyles = <
  T extends StyleSheet.NamedStyles<T> | StyleSheet.NamedStyles<any>,
>(
  stylesCallback: (injected: InjectedStyles) => T,
) => {

  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const palette = useFloroPalette();
  const colorTheme = useColorTheme();
  const paletteColor = useMemo(
    () => makePaletteColorCallback(palette),
    [palette],
  );
  const themeColor = useMemo(() => makeThemeCallback(colorTheme), [colorTheme]);
  const background = useThemeBackground();
  const injectedStyles = useMemo((): InjectedStyles => {
    return {
      palette,
      paletteColor,
      colorTheme,
      themeColor,
      background,
      width,
      height
    } as InjectedStyles;
  }, [palette, colorTheme, paletteColor, themeColor, width, height]);
  return useMemo(() => {
    return StyleSheet.create(stylesCallback(injectedStyles));
  }, [stylesCallback, injectedStyles]);
};

export const usePaletteColor = <K extends keyof Palette, S extends keyof Shade>(
  key: K,
  shade: S,
  defaultValue?: string,
) => {
  const palette = useFloroPalette();
  const paletteColor = useMemo(() => makePaletteColorCallback(palette), []);
  return useMemo(() => {
    return paletteColor(key, shade, defaultValue);
  }, [paletteColor, key, shade, defaultValue]);
};

export const useThemeColor = <K extends keyof ThemeColors>(
  key: K,
  variantKey: keyof ThemeColors[K]['variants'] | 'default' = 'default',
  defaultValue?: string,
) => {
  const colorTheme = useColorTheme();
  const themeColor = useMemo(() => makeThemeCallback(colorTheme), [colorTheme]);
  return useMemo(() => {
    return themeColor(key, variantKey as 'default', defaultValue);
  }, [themeColor, key, variantKey, defaultValue]);
};
```

Then you can do things like this

```
const useStyles = createUseStyles(({paletteColor, themeColor, background}) => ({
  container: {
    height: 72,
    width: '100%',
  },
  headContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 8,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  leftContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  debugButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    // palette API
    color: paletteColor('blue', 'regular'),
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  themeSwitcherContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 72,
    height: 32,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 16,
    // themeApi
    borderColor: themeColor('primary-border-theme'),
  },
  ...
});

interface Props {
    onOpenLanguages: () => void;
    onOpenDebug: () => void;
}

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {

    const styles = useStyles();

    /**
     * themes api
    */
    const {currentTheme, selectColorTheme} = useThemePreference()
    const themeBackground = useThemeBackground();

    /**
     * icons API
    */
    const RoundIcon = useIcon("front-page.floro-round");
    const MoonIcon = useIcon("front-page.moon");
    const SunIcon = useIcon("front-page.sun");
    const LanguageIcon = useIcon("front-page.language");
    const DropDownArrow = useIcon("front-page.drop-down-arrow");

    const ThemeIcon = useMemo(() => {
        if (currentTheme == 'dark') {
            return MoonIcon
        }
        return SunIcon;
    }, [currentTheme, MoonIcon, SunIcon]);

    const onToggleTheme = useCallback(() => {
        selectColorTheme(currentTheme == 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
    }, [currentTheme])

    /**
     * text API
    */
    // usePlainText returns a string (this cannot be debugged, since it's just ASCII)
    const debugFloroText = usePlainText(
      'header.debug_floro',
    );
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.headContainer}>
                <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
                    <RoundIcon height={56}/>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{zIndex: 200}} onPress={props.onOpenDebug}>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                        <Text style={styles.debugButton}>{debugFloroText}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onToggleTheme}>
                        <View style={styles.themeSwitcherContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.themeInnerContainer}>
                                <Animated.View style={{
                                    ...styles.themeCircle,
                                    backgroundColor: themeBackground,
                                    transform: [{
                                        translateX: themeTranslateX
                                    }]
                                }}>
                                    <ThemeIcon width={14} height={14}/>
                                </Animated.View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.divider}/>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onOpenLanguages}>
                        <View style={styles.languageSwitcherContainer}>
                            <LanguageIcon width={24} height={24}/>
                            <DropDownArrow width={24} height={24}/>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )

}
```

You should look at the repository though. It will do a much better job explaining than I can here.